# How to get duration like google map duration text format in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mapbox

I have to convert the second into something like following .

```
50 minutes
1 hour 40 minutes
1 day 2 hours 20 minutes
```

I am using mapbox and getting json as response where duration is given in seconds.Like this:

```
duration:2263.1
```

Comment: can't you do by dividing second with 60 u will get mins and add text minutes with it.?

Comment: that will fix only min problem.for larger value like day it will not be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appreciate above answers.But I was looking something like below.It solved my problem.

```
//convert to minute
    int minutes = [seconds doubleValue] / 60;

    //Convert to hours
    int hours = [seconds doubleValue] / (60 * 60);

    //Convert to days
    int days = [seconds doubleValue] / (60 * 60 * 24);

    if (days>=1)
    {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@",days,days==1?@"day":@"days"];
    }
    else if (hours>=1)
    {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d hours %d min",hours,minutes];
    }
    else
    {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d min",minutes];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
int time = timeFromApiInSeconds;
int minutes = (time / 60) % 60;
int hours = time / 3600;

    if (minutes == 0 && hours == 0){
       NSString *lblStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d Seconds", time];
    }

    if (hours == 0){
         NSString *lblStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d Minutes %02d Seconds", minutes,time];

    }
```

and so..

Another to do this is.

```
   NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *endDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:(secondsFromApi) sinceDate:startDate];

    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                             initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    NSUInteger unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:unitFlags
                                                fromDate:startDate
                                                  toDate:endDate options:0];
    NSInteger years = [components year];
    NSInteger months = [components month];
    NSInteger days = [components day];
    NSInteger minuts = [components minute];
    NSLog(@"years = %ld months = %ld days = %ld = %02d Minutes",years,months,days, minuts);
```

Even you can get seconds in components too.